# Numpy's Multivariate Normal example is not clear

Tags: numpy, covariance, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, numpy-random

I am not sure if this question fits to numpy users or mathematicians. I don't understand how the [numpy.random.multivariate_normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html)'s example works.

In the bottom of the documentation, it generates a few random values given a mean and covariance matrix,

```
mean = (1, 2)
cov = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
x = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, (3, 3))
```

and then says:

> The following is probably true, given that 0.6 is roughly twice the standard deviation. `list((x[0,0,:] - mean) < 0.6)`

I understand that this is coming from the [empirical rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule) but I don't know how the standard deviation is 0.3. Given that the variance is 1 in each axis, the std (square root of variance) should be 1 too, not 0.3.

Moreover, for multivariate variables, this 95% rule doesn't hold anymore.

Can anyone help me through this?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you refer to, refers to the property of a normal distribution in general ([enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_deviation_diagram.svg)),

[image]

and not to some `NumPy`-specific functionality. As you normalize the samples you ger, i.e., reduce the mean, the distribution is shifted around `0`, and given that the `std` of the samples is `0.3`, than most of the samples will be generated in range which is less than `3*0.3 = 0.9` from the mean, viz. 0, with the following proportion:

- ~68.27% in range [-0.3, +0.3]
- ~95.45% in range of [-0.6, +0.6]
- ~99.73% in range of [-0.9, +0.9]

so, it follows that roughly 95% of the times the X you get in the vector you produce will be smaller than 0.6, if the `std=0.3`.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, I know that. But how do you calculate the standard deviation? Isn't it the square root of variance? given that the variance is 1, the std should be 1 too not 0.3.